# Starting up with software engineering

Tags: programming-languages

I am new into the field of software engineering and wanted to learn different programming languages but I dont from where to start. Kindly give me some suggestion of programming languages that I can learn and get job companies like google.

Answer (score 0):

some steps :

- don’t skip the fundamentals :
- take time in one programming language  + solving problems (optimize
  your algorithm)
- deal with the new information as effective as possible
- stay motivated
- explain in your own words what you’ve just learned.
- Never compare yourself to other developers
- try to find a good mentor (book , videos , … trainer)

Answer (score 0):

First: Learn the basics of a language you prefer, basics like arrays, strings, class, data types, functions, calls, and attributes.

Second: Try to solve some known problems or projects by what you learnt.

Third: Try to think of different problems and how you can solve them using programming. Follow videos, and do tutorials. (now you are doing great :D)

Be patience. You will not learn this skill in a day or two. so the more hours you will invest the more your skill will get better :D

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your interest.
But you can start with Python as it is easy to use and is one of the most widely used language.
But obviously start with the basic concepts of programming as mentioned by others.